# SSRS + Report Manager looks strange

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-2012, ssrs-2012

I have an "old" SQL Server 2012 installation with Reporting Services which works very well and where the Report Manager looks like it should:

[image: Old_SSRS]

Now I've installed the same SQL Server 2012 version in a second virtual machine and **right after the installation**, the Report Manager looks some kind of broken:

[image: New_SSRS]

Also the formatting of my reports is suddenly broken.

I used:

- the same version of Windows Server 2012 ("old" server: Evaluation | "new" Server: MSDNAA)
- the same version of SQL Server 2012 ("old" server: Evaluation | "new" Server: MSDNAA)
- the same version of Internet Explorer

I have no idea what kind of bug this is ...

Comment: Possibly compare the Reportserver.Config files on both installs? There may be something in there.

Comment: On the second VM, is / was there an older version of SQL installed?

Comment: @NickyvV No. It was a clean, new installation. (And thanks for embedding the pictures)

Comment: In your screenshots, it looks like you have IE Compatibility View on in the second screenshot but not the first. Is this just something you were testing? What happens when you change this setting?

Comment: @IanPreston You're right! When I change the setting everything looks fine. THANKS! I don't know why the IE CW was off when I opened "new" Report Manager. I didn't changed anything. Strange. Also I don't know why there is no compatibility issue when I load the "old" Report Manager.

Comment: Great, thanks for the update, I've added the comment as an answer now since it seems to have solved the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your screenshots, it looks like you have IE **Compatibility View** enabled in the second screenshot (i.e. the new Report Server) but not the first (i.e. the old Report Server).

Making sure both environments are being viewed the same way through IE should either solve the issue or help eliminate this as a possibility.